# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException when input is zero

Tags: java

Here is my code for calculating Fibonacci of n. I don't get when `n = 0`, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` is raised. From `fib` function when `n = 0`, it should `return 0`. What cause this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Fibonacci {
    public static int fib(int n) {
        int[] t = new int[n + 1];
        t[0] = 0;
        t[1] = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i < t.length; i++) {
            t[i] = t[i - 1] + t[i - 2];
        }
        return t[n];
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (;;) {
            if (!in.hasNextInt()) {
                in.next();
                continue;
            }
            int n = in.nextInt();
            if (n >= 0) {
                System.out.println(fib(n));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input!");
            }
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When n = 0, the array `int[] t = new int[n + 1];` holds only 1 element. However, you try to allocate two elements:

`t[0] = 0;`
`t[1] = 1;`

Comment: Wonderful :D. Fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code can be much simpler! Why it is giving you this error though, is because when you input 0, the array is created of elements ( 0 + 1 ), so 1 element. You then try to give two elements values. Heres an example of the fibonacci sequence using recursion

```
public int fibonacci(int n){
    if(n == 0)
        return 0;
    else if(n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this running time of your code is O(2^n).